# json unmarshall not working on golang proto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am getting this response for a http request

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImZCRXFDSnFER21hMUxLZUtoZUVxcSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi0xY3p5M3Vpa21pNjJ0dWN4LnVzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw0OTAiLCJhdWQiOiJhdXRoLXNlcnZpY2Ui...",
  "scope": "read:sample",
  "expires_in": 86400,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

I want to unmarshal this response into the following proto in golang:

```
message Token {
  // jwt access token
  string access_token = 1;
  // scope of the token
  string scope = 2;
  // expiration time
  int32 expires_in = 3;
  // token type
  string token_type = 4;
}
```

Also, Here is the genreated go struct:

```
type Token struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    // jwt access token
    AccessToken string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=access_token,json=accessToken,proto3" json:"access_token,omitempty"`
    // scope of the token
    Scope string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=scope,proto3" json:"scope,omitempty"`
    // expiration time
    ExpiresIn int32 `protobuf:"varint,3,opt,name=expires_in,json=expiresIn,proto3" json:"expires_in,omitempty"`
    // token type
    TokenType string `protobuf:"bytes,4,opt,name=token_type,json=tokenType,proto3" json:"token_type,omitempty"`
}
```

I tried `json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&token)` from `json/encoding` package.
Also tried this:

```
    token := new(v1_stubs.Token)
    if err := jsonpb.Unmarshal(resp.Body, token); err != nil {
        log.Context(ctx).Errorf("failed to decode `get token` response")
        return nil, err
    }
```

Where `v1_stubs.Token` is generated go sturuct of above mentioned proto.

**The issue is:**
I am getting the as output when I convert token into json:

```
{
    "token": {
        "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImZCRXFDSnFER21hMUxLZUtoZUVxcSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi0xY3p5M3Vpa21pNjJ0dWN4LnV...",
        "scope": "read:sample",
        "expires_in": "\"\u0006Bearer",
        "token_type": ""
    }
}
```

It looks like some data missing in `expires_in` field and `token_type` merged into `expires_in`.

Comment: Can you share the generated definition of the `v1_stubs.Token` ?

Comment: Added the generated def. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a from scratch example. Perhaps you can reproduce it and see where your local setup diverges from this one? The official documentation for the [`jsonpb`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb) package says that  it is deprecated in favor of [`"google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson), so I've included two samples of code, both of which seem to work as intended.

```protobuf
// ex.proto
syntax = "proto3";

message Token {
  // jwt access token
  string access_token = 1;
  // scope of the token
  string scope = 2;
  // expiration time
  int32 expires_in = 3;
  // token type
  string token_type = 4;
}
```

I downloaded a fresh install of the tools from
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v21.12

```bash
$ unzip protoc-21.12-linux-x86_64.zip
$ PATH=$(pwd)/bin:$PATH
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
$ protoc -I=./ --go_out=./ --go_opt=Mex.proto=this/ex ex.proto
$ cd this
$ go mod init this
```

In this `this` directory, create the `main_jsonpb.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "this/ex"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"
)

func main() {
    d := `{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImZCRXFDSnFER21hMUxLZUtoZUVxcSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi0xY3p5M3Vpa21pNjJ0dWN4LnVzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw0OTAiLCJhdWQiOiJhdXRoLXNlcnZpY2Ui...",
  "scope": "read:sample",
  "expires_in": 86400,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}`
    var pr ex.Token
    if err := jsonpb.UnmarshalString(d, &pr); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to unmarshal json: %v", err)
    }
    f := &jsonpb.Marshaler{
        Indent: "  ",
    }
    fmt.Println(f.MarshalToString(&pr))
}
```

and the `main_protojson.go` file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "this/ex"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
)

func main() {
    d := []byte(`{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImZCRXFDSnFER21hMUxLZUtoZUVxcSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi0xY3p5M3Vpa21pNjJ0dWN4LnVzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw0OTAiLCJhdWQiOiJhdXRoLXNlcnZpY2Ui...",
  "scope": "read:sample",
  "expires_in": 86400,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}`)
    var pr ex.Token
    if err := protojson.Unmarshal(d, &pr); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to unmarshal json: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(protojson.Format(&pr))
}
```

Then execute them:

```bash
$ go mod tidy
$ go run main_jsonpb.go
{
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImZCRXFDSnFER21hMUxLZUtoZUVxcSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi0xY3p5M3Vpa21pNjJ0dWN4LnVzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw0OTAiLCJhdWQiOiJhdXRoLXNlcnZpY2Ui...",
  "scope": "read:sample",
  "expiresIn": 86400,
  "tokenType": "Bearer"
} <nil>
$ go run main_protojson.go
{
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImZCRXFDSnFER21hMUxLZUtoZUVxcSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi0xY3p5M3Vpa21pNjJ0dWN4LnVzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw0OTAiLCJhdWQiOiJhdXRoLXNlcnZpY2Ui...",
  "scope": "read:sample",
  "expiresIn": 86400,
  "tokenType": "Bearer"
}
```